# Is there analysis library for stress-strain data?

Tags: energy, experimental-physics, classical-mechanics, elasticity, stress-strain

I have three column data that has time-displacement-force from 1D tensile/compression test. Now I would like to get the standard mechanical properties of the material, like Young modulus, yield stress/strain, strain hardening/softening exponent, Fracture toughness, work done...

Is there algorithms/libraries available that will do it for me or do I have to code them myself?

Comment: I don't know of any software, but at least for the Young's modulus, yield stress and work it will be very easy. I doubt that you can get the fracture toughness from these data.

Comment: Yes, its rather simple exercise, but don't want to invent the wheel again. I know that others have the same problem and the solution is usually to buy 5 000$ software that works like a black box. There might be some algorithms written already and open source.